# How to resolve my Angular DOM rendering problem

Tags: angular, ngfor, dom-manipulation

I have this HTML where I want to render all my items in an array and also react to the updates from the service when some item changed (updated partially like a 'name').

The problem come in when I send the update and the service returns the array.slice(), there seems to be some problem because I would be able to see the other items in the array  but not the one which I recently updated. The communication between the component and the service works like this. There are three components:

1. listComponent that renders the array.
2. editComponent that does the update and edit and sends it to component 3
3. serviceComponent that have all the arrays and does the CRUD operations. Sends the updated value to the service.

Here is my listComponent.html and its .ts code:

```html
      <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
        <h4>{{item.heading}}</h4>
        <p>{{item.details}}
          <a [routerLink]="[i]"><span>Link here</span></a>
        </p>
      </div>
```

The .ts file:

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items = this.itemsService.getitems()
    this.subscription = this.itemsService.itemChanged.subscribe((items : Item[]) => {
      this.items = items;
    })
  }
```

Here's a code snippet of the Service.ts:

```js
export class itemsService {
    itemChanged = new Subject<Item[]>();
    private items: Item[] = [
        new Item(
            'Heading-1',
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis, dignissimos inventore, d.'
        ),
        new Item(
            'Heading-2',
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis')
]

getItems() {
        return this.items.slice();
    }
}
    updateItem(index: number, newItem: Item) {
        this.items[index] = newItem;
        this.itemChanged.next(this.items.slice());
    }
```

And here is the editComponent.ts:

```js
    onSubmit() {
        if (this.editMode){
            console.log(this.editMode)
            this.itemsService.updateItem(this.id, this.iForm.value);
        } 
}
```

The id in the editComponent is received from the params.

Comment: Please show the service code.

Comment: Instead of doing this in ```ngOnInit()``` do it in ```ngOnChanges()```

Comment: I imagine your function this.itemsService.getitems() return an Observable -looks like a `return httpClient.get(...)`. So you need subscribe to the function and equal this.items to this function in subscribe function. NOTE: An observable is not executed until you subscribe (or use pipe async). BTW To use a pipe async (if you inject the service as public):`<div *ngFor="let itemsService.getitems() of works|async; let i = index">`

Comment: @Eliseo This is actually just a return statement with a slice of the array.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton updated the question with services.ts.

Comment: @shagatbing, It's looks like work: see a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yxxrud?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fitems.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts). NOTE In the stackblitz also I added a new variable BehaviorSubject (if you want use instead a simple Subject)

Comment: @Eliseo actually i found out what the problem is. I tried everything, making it an observable, trying to update the item onChanges. The problem was in the **forms**. I have passed on the value to the update method by using the  'formName.value' which i never thought would be where the problem was, thats why u didnt see the code here. Anyways i canged it, making a constant and getting all the value out then sending it then to the update method.

Comment: @Eliseo ya thats quite a niche trick btw using behaviorSubject. It will save a lot of variable haha. I havent used it likewise. ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with some naming convention in the forms. For eg.

```html
<input name = 'name' ngModel name='itemName'>
```

Here, I thought the 'ngModel name' would be the key of the {object Object} but instead the 'name' is the key.

Comment: There no mention about inputs in the questions. It is missing [mre]

Answer (score 0):

You have two approaches to solve your problem. Actually it's all about detect changes in a view.

First way - just add `ChangeDetectorRef` to your component. Like this:

```
constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {} 

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items = this.itemsService.getitems()
    this.subscription = this.itemsService.itemChanged.subscribe((items : Item[]) => {
      this.items = items;
      this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    })
  }
```

But as mark above in comments - that's not the best solution. The best is to use `async` pipe, you may do it this way:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items$ | async; let i = index">
  ...
```

and in you component file:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items$ = this.itemsService.itemChanged.pipe(
      startWith(this.itemsService.getitems()),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I have added more info on the question. Can you plis check it again? I might have given too little infor at first. ty.

Comment: seems everything should work

Comment: @AntonMarineko ya its working now. Though it was a whole different problem where I didnt see it coming from. thanks anyways